# Asp.net MVC 5 dynamically created button and calls to a javascript function with argument

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

From my razor view i have a loop for creating some datas inside a table.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ItemModel) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Brand)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PurchaseQty)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesQty)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stock)
        </td>
        <td>
            <button onclick="showModal(item.ItemCode);">Show Details/button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

My javascript function is to accept one parameter (when button clicks) and print it inside a modal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showModal(itemCode)
    {
        var mod = $('#myModal');
        mod.modal();
        $('#recordId').html(itemCode);
    }
</script>
```

I got exception when i run above code, and it works fine when i use some manual input parameters like 123.

```
<button onclick="showModal(123);">Show Details/button>
```

i want to call this method by using dynamic parameter ( value from loop ), whats wrong here? help me!

Comment: Check your rendered HTML. Don't you need to add '@' to item.ItemCode?
So: "showModal(@item.ItemCode);"

Comment: Exactly , I have missed '@'

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `"showModal(@item.ItemCode);"` ,
i missed @ at the beginning.